# Extending the width of a sub-div to 100%

Tags: css, layout, html

I have a problem here, which I've not come across before and can't seem to think of any reasonable solution that doesn't require a) breaking apart the existing layout, or b) creating a new, weird layout.

Below, I will demonstrate what I am trying to acheive. I've seen it many times on other sites:

```
<div class="MainContainerDIV" style="width: 960px; height: 100%;">
    <div class="SubDIV" style=width: fill up the browser viewport completely, even extending outside of the parent div; height: 150px;">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could someone please give me some pointers as to how I should go about this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply `position: absolute` to the sub div, it removes it from the document flow, and you can then specify a width of 100%. You can see the results in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/pcdRC/). One thing to bear in mind, is that if you apply absolute or relative positioning to the parent div, it will no longer work.

Comment: Thank you very much, @magicalex. Here is the final version incase anyone wants to extend both sides: http://jsfiddle.net/pcdRC/7/